# Tips to reduce the execution time

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query that works well and gives me the results as expected.

But the execution time of the query is close to 10 mins. Is there any way that I could make it run faster? I'm assuming that it is because of the Lead-lag approach. Any thoughts or suggestions, would be much appreciated.  Im using MS - SQL . the underlying tables have close to 40K records.

Thanks in advance!

SQL query:

```
SELECT  *
INTO    #temp1
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            NoteID
            ,parentRef
            ,CREATEDBY
            ,Employee_Name
            ,Supervisor
            ,Office
            ,CreatedDate
            ,CreatedTime
            ,Body
            ,Headline
            ,TypeCode
            ,b.Name
            ,LEAD(PARENTREF) OVER (Partition BY ParentRef ORDER BY CreatedDate, CreatedTime)        AS next_ParentRef
            ,LEAD(NoteID) OVER (PARTITION BY ParentRef ORDER BY CreatedDate, CreatedTime)           AS next_NotedID
            ,LEAD(Employee_Name) OVER (PARTITION BY ParentRef ORDER BY CreatedDate, CreatedTime)    AS next_EmployeeName
            ,LEAD(Supervisor) OVER (PARTITION BY ParentRef ORDER BY CreatedDate, CreatedTime)       AS next_Supervisor
            ,LEAD(Office) OVER (PARTITION BY ParentRef ORDER BY CreatedDate, CreatedTime)           AS next_Office
            ,LEAD(CREATEDDATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ParentRef ORDER BY CreatedDate, CreatedTime)      AS next_CreatedDate
            ,LEAD(CREATEDTIME) OVER (PARTITION BY ParentRef ORDER BY CreatedDate, CreatedTime)      AS next_CreatedTime
            ,LEAD(Body) OVER (PARTITION BY ParentRef ORDER BY CreatedDate, CreatedTime)             AS next_Body
            ,LEAD(Headline) OVER (PARTITION BY ParentRef ORDER BY CreatedDate, CreatedTime)         AS next_Headline
            ,LEAD(Typecode) OVER (PARTITION BY ParentRef ORDER BY CreatedDate, CreatedTime)         AS next_Typecode
            ,LEAD(NAME) OVER (PARTITION BY ParentRef ORDER BY CreatedDate, CreatedTime)             AS next_Name
        FROM
            Stg.Note        n
        LEFT JOIN
            dbo.NoteType    b ON n.TYPECODE         = b.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            dbo.Employee    e ON N.CREATEDBY        = e.UserName
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            dbo.[Transfer]  I ON e.Employee_Name    = I.AdjusterName
                            AND dbo.ConvertIGDateTime(n.CREATEDDATE, n.CREATEDTIME) BETWEEN DateStart AND ISNULL(
                                                                                                                Dateend
                                                                                                                ,GETDATE()
                                                                                                            )
) b
WHERE(
        NAME        = 'File Review'
AND next_Name       = 'File Review'
)
AND (
    TYPECODE        = '1200005'
AND next_Typecode   = '1200005'
)
AND (
    (HEADLINE LIKE '%Follow up letter%')
AND (next_Headline LIKE '%Follow up letter%')
)
AND CONVERT(date, (CONVERT(varchar (10), next_createddate)))    > DATEADD(
                                                                    DAY
                                                                    ,10
                                                                    ,CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar (10), createddate))
                                                                )
AND PARENTREF                                                   = '2002861';



--existing row
SELECT  a.*
INTO    #temp2
FROM
        #temp1      a
JOIN
        Stg.Note    b ON b.PARENTREF    = a.PARENTREF
                    AND a.NoteID    = b.NoteID;


---- NextRow 
SELECT
        stg.*
        ,c.next_Name
        ,c.next_EmployeeName
        ,c.next_Supervisor
        ,c.next_Office
INTO    #temp3
FROM
        #temp1      c
JOIN
        Stg.Note    stg ON stg.PARENTREF    = c.next_ParentRef
                        AND stg.NoteID      = c.next_NotedID;


SELECT
    curr.NoteID
    ,curr.PARENTREF
    ,dbo.ConvertIGDateTime(curr.CREATEDDATE, curr.CREATEDTIME)                          AS CreatedDateTime
    ,curr.Employee_Name
    ,curr.Supervisor
    ,curr.Office
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(curr.BODY AS NVARCHAR (MAX)), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '')    AS Body
    ,CAST(curr.HEADLINE AS NVARCHAR (MAX))                                              AS Headline
    ,curr.TYPECODE
    ,curr.Name
FROM
    #temp2 curr
UNION
SELECT
    lf.NoteID
    ,lf.PARENTREF
    ,dbo.ConvertIGDateTime(lf.CREATEDDATE, lf.CREATEDTIME)                          AS CreatedDateTime
    ,lf.next_EmployeeName
    ,lf.next_Supervisor
    ,lf.next_Office
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(lf.BODY AS NVARCHAR (MAX)), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '')  AS Body
    ,CAST(lf.HEADLINE AS NVARCHAR (MAX))                                            AS Headline
    ,lf.TYPECODE
    ,lf.next_Name
FROM
    #temp3 lf
ORDER BY
    PARENTREF
    ,CreatedDateTime;


DROP TABLE #temp1;
DROP TABLE #temp2;
DROP TABLE #temp3;
```

Comment: we need to see the DDL with indexes, and execution plan. I'd upload that to [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). However, i'd start with not using functions where possible, like `dbo.ConvertIGDateTime`. Also, if you have an index on your date fields they won't be used since you are using functions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Possibly better for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or [DBA](https://DBA.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Larnu In it's current form, not on Code Review. Needs more context, including the schema of the DB.

Comment: @Mast Agreed, it still needs improvements, where ever the question "ends up". Also, I noticed that you have expressions in your `WHERE` like `HEADLINE like '%Follow up letter%'`. That'll be awful for performance as well, due to the leading WildCard; causing the query to also be non-SARGable.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the function ConvertIGDateTime and write the functionality into the statement. It is likely being calculated for each row and is preventing the date fields from being sargable.
If possible, remove the %% from the headline field clauses.

Change the end of the WHERE clause to:

```
and DateStart > CAST(n.CREATEDDATE AS DATETIME) + CAST(n.CREATEDTIME AS DATETIME) 
and (Dateend < CAST(n.CREATEDDATE AS DATETIME) + CAST(n.CREATEDTIME AS DATETIME)
or Dateend is null and getdate() < CAST(n.CREATEDDATE AS DATETIME) + CAST(n.CREATEDTIME AS DATETIME))
```

In addition, the clause: `and  convert(date, (convert(varchar(10), next_createddate))) > dateadd(day, 10, convert(date, convert(varchar(10), createddate)))`

can use indexes and will perform better as:

```
and cast(next_createddate as date) > dateadd(day, 10, cast(createddate as date))
```

Comment: This is probably more of a comment in it's current form. At least provide some sample SQL to show how the query could be changed to cater for these changes. Also, without knowing the OP's requirements, how would you recommend that they remove a clause like `HEADLINE like '%Follow up letter%'` and keep similar/the same functionality?

Comment: I cannot remove the filter HEADLINE like '%Follow up letter% because that's how I get my accurate results.

Comment: @Lamu Noted and code added. I think it is the function that is the cause of slowness.